# Programmatically creating validation list

Tags: excel, vba, validation

I have an array of data that is coming in to the VBA code from an external source. I want to be able to assign that data to use as a validation in a dropdown box in a cell in one of the sheets in this workbook. However, I do not want to copy that data into a sheet and then use a named range - there may be quite a lot of data, and that would not feel very efficient!

I'm sure there must be a way - but I haven't found one yet. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Place the data in some text file delimiting it with comma eg(a,b,c).
2. Read that data using VBA into a string variable eg ValidationList.
3. Use some thing like this

   With Range("A1").Validation
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:=ValidationList
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
   End With

Comment: Here replace "A1" with the cell you want to validate.

Comment: Thanks Thunder for the quick and accurate answer.  The only issue with it is having to change the array into a comma separated string, which makes it a little more wordy.  However it does what I need - thanks!

Comment: It may also be useful to add the line .Delete after With Range("A1").Validation to remove any previous validation in that cell, rather than cause an error.

Comment: This works on Excel 2007 for me, but not 2003.  I can't believe it is that recent of a feature - is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little trick I used, in this "list" is an ArrayList:

```
Dim ValidateList As String
For Each x In list
ValidateList = ValidateList + x + Chr(44)
Next
 With Sheets(yoursheet).Range(yourCell).Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
     xlBetween, Formula1:=ValidateList
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
```

Might seem a bit crude, but I think it works without any problems :)