# Filling unique dates in a dynamic validation list

Tags: arrays, validation, date, excel, vba

I am trying to fill two cells with two different dynamic validation lists. The first is array of strings and the second is an array of dates.

I am using the following code.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("G21")) Is Nothing Then

        Call getValidationSeries

    End If

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("I21")) Is Nothing Then

        Call getValidationExpiry

    End If
End Sub
```

Followed by
    Sub getValidationSeries()

```
Dim valseries(100) As String
     ~~~Other declarations

     ~~~~ code to fill identify unique values in valseries

Range("Charts!G21").Select
   With Selection.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:=Join(valseries, ",")
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With

End Sub
```

And

```
Sub getValidationExpiry()

Dim valseries(100) As Date
     ~~~Other declarations

     ~~~~ code to fill identify unique dates in valseries

Range("Charts!I21").Select
   With Selection.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:=Join(valseries, ",")
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With

End Sub
```

The Question

The above is working fine for the first sub where valseries is an array of strings. But is not working when valseries is an array of dates in the second sub. I know I cannot use Join in the second function because its a date variable. When I declared valseries as a Variant instead of a Date variable, it worked but it converted all dates into strings. I need them as dates (of course I can reconvert them back into dates but thats not efficient)

Any clue? I dont want to store the unique values in a range.

I looked at these (which were similar to what I did for strings) but are not of much help for dates.

[Programmatically creating Excel VBA validation list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4497854/programmatically-creating-excel-vba-validation-list)

[Excel Validation Drop Down list using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18885513/excel-validation-drop-down-list-using-vba)

[Excel: How to create dynamic data validation list based on data table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19730067/excel-how-to-create-dynamic-data-validation-list-based-on-data-table)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I was making some mistake in creation unique values of the valseries. Declaring valseries as Variant works. Declaring valseries as Date does not work. Thanks for the views anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple working example that may help you:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim DateArray(1 To 3) As Date
    Dim str As String

    DateArray(1) = DateSerial(2004, 12, 25)
    DateArray(2) = DateSerial(1945, 1, 18)
    DateArray(3) = DateSerial(2020, 7, 1)

    For i = LBound(DateArray) To UBound(DateArray)
        If str = "" Then
            str = CStr(DateArray(i))
        Else
            str = str & "," & CStr(DateArray(i))
        End If
    Next i

    ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "dd mmmm yyyy"
    With ActiveCell.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:=str
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Many thanks for the example and having a look. This does the same thing as join except for forcing the date format. As I posted, the mistake was somewhere else.